# How to put result of MYSQL DISTINCT QUERY in a PHP VARIABLE?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, concatenation, distinct

i've a problem trying to get multiple values and concatenate them inside a single php string variable.

The idea is to use a MYSQL DISTINCT STATEMENT on a single column of the table like this:

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT(COLUMN) from table where <multiple conditions>";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$suppliers = $row['COLUMN'];
}
```

I'm sure there are 2 records in my database I want to obtain with two distinct values: 'PLENITUDE' and 'IREN' but i dont know how to concatenate them inside the variable like this:

'PLENITUDE-IREN'

And i'm not so expert .. it seems the query is OK but if I echo $suppliers the result is null.

Comment: I don't know what this has to do with concatenation. Do you want to concatenate the results? Something like `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: I would check the values the get in `$row` as well.

Comment: Make sure you have PHP error reporting enabled on full. You should be getting a Warning due to the bug you have. If you do not see a warning, it means you have error reporting disabled.

Comment: Hi, as I wrote I need to concatenate distinct values obtained  in a single PHP variables.

Comment: Nigel, IF I echo the $row, it tells me: ArrayArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$suppliers = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  if($suppliers !== '') $suppliers .= '-';
  $suppliers .= $row['COLUMN'];
}
echo $suppliers;
```

Comment: Found the problem ! It works now. Great answer Aysun!

Comment: i am happy it worked